# Inconsistent Clickhouse database query performance

Tags: performance, database, query

Folks,

Clickhouse Server version: 22.8.21 (have tried a variety of 22.x and 23.x versions as supported by `clickhouse-backup` to restore my data with for testing, none seemed to improve the query performance).

I'm finding some really odd behaviour with a clickhouse server here (both on a dedicated machine and a docker image with the same data loaded).

Sometimes queries take ~50ms to complete, others take upwards of 250s to complete (and if you run the 200s query often enough it'll populate into some cache from all appearances and get down to ~50ms).

The data set is in a table with a simple index (the queries are not running across the primary index so it'll scan the entire 3.5Gb data set).

```
CREATE TABLE `cdrs_processed` (
    `Id` UInt64,
    `Direction` String,
    `Time` DateTime('UTC'),
    `CallID` String,
    `CorrelationID` String,
... <snip> ...
)  
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(Id)  
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Time)  
ORDER BY (Id,Time)  
PRIMARY KEY Id  
SETTINGS index\_granularity = 8192  
COMMENT 'Processed and enriched CDR records';
```

The query being run is this `SELECT * FROM cdrs_processed WHERE CorrelationID='<some guid>' ORDER BY Id;`  Different guids have different query response times.
The interesting parts here are these:

1. Running a PCAP across the traffic, on a performant query (ie the records are returned in ~50ms) the server responds first with the column headers and then the data.  When a CorrelationID value is selected that results in a slow read, the PCAP traffic shows the connection and query, then a whole bunch of TCP KeepAlive messages, and only then (if it didn't time out) does it send the column headers and the data.
2. The deployed clickhouse-server software is running on an AWS EC2 r5a.xlarge node receiving minimal queries (1-2/second), and it's spinning the EC2 instance's 4 vCPU's at 100% for some bizarre reason.  This server has the same query performance problems as when we take the data from a backup and restore it to a local docker image running clickhouse-server on a developers system.
3. When debugging the query using the `clickhouse-client` and running `set send_logs_level='trace';` before running the query. If it is a performant query we get the fun logs of.

```
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:28:27.307306 [ 287 ] {5c35e3ba-15d3-494e-991b-9a93674ae9af} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 172.28.0.1:47140) SELECT * FROM nextvoice.cdrs_processed WHERE CorrelationID='E3065F87-3CB9-4C58-A12D-66A686B8C53D'; (stage: Complete)
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:28:27.322028 [ 287 ] {5c35e3ba-15d3-494e-991b-9a93674ae9af} <Debug> InterpreterSelectQuery: MergeTreeWhereOptimizer: condition "CorrelationID = 'E3065F87-3CB9-4C58-A12D-66A686B8C53D'" moved to PREWHERE
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:28:27.328348 [ 287 ] {5c35e3ba-15d3-494e-991b-9a93674ae9af} <Debug> InterpreterSelectQuery: MergeTreeWhereOptimizer: condition "CorrelationID = 'E3065F87-3CB9-4C58-A12D-66A686B8C53D'" moved to PREWHERE
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:28:27.331671 [ 287 ] {5c35e3ba-15d3-494e-991b-9a93674ae9af} <Trace> ContextAccess (default): Access granted: SELECT(Id, Direction, Time, CallID, .... <snip>
```

and all is well, if it is a slow query, then it gets interesting.  The first line of that log line is printed accordingly with the timestamp, the second and subsequent lines do no get printed until the query completes, but contain the timestamp as if they were published at the correct time. ie.

This line is printed.

```
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:30:06.838300 [ 287 ] {f9d77d15-8b7b-42d7-a344-eb0ad09ee690} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 172.28.0.1:47140) SELECT * FROM nextvoice.cdrs_processed WHERE CorrelationID='03FBC351-48A1-4E3A-8257-AA97ED75F7A5'; (stage: Complete)
```

Then we get nothing until `2023.09.06 05:31:35.309735` where we get all the rest of the trace lines printed such as those below. (I took a video of this happening).

```
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:30:06.860733 [ 287 ] {f9d77d15-8b7b-42d7-a344-eb0ad09ee690} <Trace> InterpreterSelectQuery: FetchColumns -> Complete
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:30:06.864526 [ 287 ] {f9d77d15-8b7b-42d7-a344-eb0ad09ee690} <Debug> nextvoice.cdrs_processed (c8be24d5-22dd-4344-a9bf-10db9eabc46d) (SelectExecutor): Key condition: unknown
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:30:06.865117 [ 287 ] {f9d77d15-8b7b-42d7-a344-eb0ad09ee690} <Debug> nextvoice.cdrs_processed (c8be24d5-22dd-4344-a9bf-10db9eabc46d) (SelectExecutor): MinMax index condition: unknown
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:30:06.880895 [ 287 ] {f9d77d15-8b7b-42d7-a344-eb0ad09ee690} <Debug> nextvoice.cdrs_processed (c8be24d5-22dd-4344-a9bf-10db9eabc46d) (SelectExecutor): Selected 62/62 parts by partition key, 62 parts by primary key, 1873/1873 marks by primary key, 1873 marks to read from 62 ranges
[2f7418aeaf9c] 2023.09.06 05:31:35.309735 [ 287 ] {f9d77d15-8b7b-42d7-a344-eb0ad09ee690} <Debug> nextvoice.cdrs_processed (c8be24d5-22dd-4344-a9bf-10db9eabc46d) (SelectExecutor): Reading approx. 3852688 rows with 4 streams
```

4. Next, the server0 has been quiet for the last 6+ hours, there have been no queries to it of any kind, only thing being sent to it are prometheus metrics scrapes. Yet the trace logs are constantly scrolling past with

```
2023.09.06 10:51:06.000598 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Debug> MergeTask::PrepareStage: Merging 2 parts: from 202309_75514_76920_1105 to 202309_76921_76921_0 into Wide
2023.09.06 10:51:06.000762 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Debug> MergeTask::PrepareStage: Selected MergeAlgorithm: Horizontal
2023.09.06 10:51:06.000789 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Debug> MergeTreeSequentialSource: Reading 10 marks from part 202309_75514_76920_1105, total 70966 rows starting from the beginning of the part
2023.09.06 10:51:06.000924 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Debug> MergeTreeSequentialSource: Reading 2 marks from part 202309_76921_76921_0, total 34 rows starting from the beginning of the part
2023.09.06 10:51:06.029025 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Debug> MergeTask::MergeProjectionsStage: Merge sorted 71000 rows, containing 10 columns (10 merged, 0 gathered) in 0.028416545 sec., 2498544.4219203987 rows/sec., 805.83 MiB/sec.
2023.09.06 10:51:06.030461 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Trace> MergedBlockOutputStream: filled checksums 202309_75514_76921_1106 (state Temporary)
2023.09.06 10:51:06.030766 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Trace> system.trace_log (b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962): Renaming temporary part tmp_merge_202309_75514_76921_1106 to 202309_75514_76921_1106.
2023.09.06 10:51:06.030821 [ 317 ] {b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106} <Trace> system.trace_log (b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962) (MergerMutator): Merged 2 parts: from 202309_75514_76920_1105 to 202309_76921_76921_0
2023.09.06 10:51:06.030869 [ 317 ] {} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage to apply mutate/merge in b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962::202309_75514_76921_1106: 43.34 MiB.
2023.09.06 10:51:07.000655 [ 335 ] {} <Trace> AsynchronousMetrics: MemoryTracking: was 804.53 MiB, peak 3.11 GiB, will set to 807.54 MiB (RSS), difference: 3.01 MiB
2023.09.06 10:51:07.593604 [ 349 ] {} <Trace> SystemLog (system.asynchronous_metric_log): Flushing system log, 2030 entries to flush up to offset 5643012
2023.09.06 10:51:07.594682 [ 349 ] {} <Debug> DiskLocal: Reserving 1.00 MiB on disk `default`, having unreserved 41.29 GiB.
2023.09.06 10:51:07.595125 [ 349 ] {} <Trace> MergedBlockOutputStream: filled checksums 202309_2778_2778_0 (state Temporary)
2023.09.06 10:51:07.595304 [ 349 ] {} <Trace> system.asynchronous_metric_log (65e48ced-63b1-49f3-b373-fe52139c8fd6): Renaming temporary part tmp_insert_202309_2778_2778_0 to 202309_64623_64623_0.
2023.09.06 10:51:07.595444 [ 349 ] {} <Trace> SystemLog (system.asynchronous_metric_log): Flushed system log up to offset 5643012
2023.09.06 10:51:07.769264 [ 327 ] {} <Trace> system.trace_log (b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962): Found 2 old parts to remove.
2023.09.06 10:51:07.769291 [ 327 ] {} <Debug> system.trace_log (b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962): Removing part from filesystem 202309_75514_76856_1041
2023.09.06 10:51:07.769959 [ 327 ] {} <Debug> system.trace_log (b09755a5-5004-4d4e-adef-82f4b86b4962): Removing part from filesystem 202309_76857_76857_0
2023.09.06 10:51:10.302387 [ 475 ] {} <Debug> DNSResolver: Updating DNS cache
2023.09.06 10:51:10.302543 [ 475 ] {} <Debug> DNSResolver: Updated DNS cache
2023.09.06 10:51:10.924813 [ 350 ] {} <Trace> SystemLog (system.metric_log): Flushing system log, 7 entries to flush up to offset 19458
2023.09.06 10:51:10.932845 [ 350 ] {} <Debug> DiskLocal: Reserving 1.00 MiB on disk `default`, having unreserved 41.29 GiB.
2023.09.06 10:51:10.935552 [ 350 ] {} <Trace> MergedBlockOutputStream: filled checksums 202309_2590_2590_0 (state Temporary)
2023.09.06 10:51:10.935969 [ 350 ] {} <Trace> system.metric_log (8c45d18c-4f03-43de-9848-28490ac69588): Renaming temporary part tmp_insert_202309_2590_2590_0 to 202309_60226_60226_0.
2023.09.06 10:51:10.936121 [ 471 ] {} <Debug> system.metric_log (8c45d18c-4f03-43de-9848-28490ac69588) (MergerMutator): Selected 6 parts from 202309_59866_60221_71 to 202309_60226_60226_0
2023.09.06 10:51:10.936149 [ 471 ] {} <Debug> DiskLocal: Reserving 1.00 MiB on disk `default`, having unreserved 41.29 GiB.
2023.09.06 10:51:10.936234 [ 302 ] {8c45d18c-4f03-43de-9848-28490ac69588::202309_59866_60226_72} <Debug> MergeTask::PrepareStage: Merging 6 parts: from 202309_59866_60221_71 to 202309_60226_60226_0 into Compact
```

which indicates to me that it's trying to process some form of queries/merges/inserts.

The one client application (that has been shut off for 6 hours) at most processes 1-2 requests/second.  There could be an update request in that mix but i can replace those with an insert instead and rely on the `ReplacingMergeTree` behaviour.

Can anyone provide ideas as to where/what to look for something that needs changing or tweaking.  The lack of index across the data doesn't seem to be a problem for some of the queries since the sequential scan is performant enough at this stage. We're trying to get reliable query performance so we can identify the correct indexes/materialized views/projections we need across the data to see how they affect things, but since we can't get reliable performance from clickhouse..).